# Inactivar botón según estado del documento

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo el siguiente formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
    <select onchange="cargarDocumento()" name="c_almacen">
      <option selected="selected" value = '0'></option>
      <?php
         while ( $registro=ifx_fetch_row($g_idq)  )
         {
           echo '<option value = '.$registro['c_almacen'].'>'.$registro['c_almacen']." -- ".$registro['d_almacen'].'</option>';  
         }
      ?>
    </select></td>
  <td width="247"><div  id="contenedorDocumento"><div class="Estilo2">Debe seleccionar un almac&eacute;n</div></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="625">
     <tr>
       <td width="156">&nbsp;</td>
       <td width="58"><input type="button" onclick="ejecutar('D')" name="diferencias" value="DIFERENCIAS" /></td>
       <td width="89"><input type="button" disabled onclick="ejecutar('A')" name="ajustar" value="AJUSTAR" /></td>
```

En la parte de seleccionar el almacén se habilita la opción para salir el documento con la función contenedorDocumento

```
function cargarDocumento()
    { 
        var conce,contenedor; 

            contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedorDocumento"); 
            c_almac = eval("document.form1.c_almacen.options[document.form1.c_almacen.selectedIndex].value");
            ajax=nuevoAjax(); 

        ajax.open("POST","ajax_documento_teo.php",true); 

        ajax.onreadystatechange=function() 

//se ejecuta el ajx del documento_teo.php

$c_almace =$_POST['c_alm'];

?>
<td>
        <?php
         $sql = "SELECT UNIQUE(cs_teorico) documento FROM h_inventario_teo WHERE c_almacen = ".$c_almace." AND (estado = 'P' OR estado = 'D')";

         p_query($sql);
         //echo "--1-<br> $sql <br><br>";
        ?>
        Documento: <select name="documento">
        <option value = ''></option> 
        <?php

         while ( $registro=ifx_fetch_row($g_idq)  )
          {
           echo '<option value = '.$registro['documento'].'>'.$registro['documento'].'</option>';  
          }

        ?>
        </select></td>
```

No sé como hacer que el botón de ajustar solo se habilite cuando el estado del documento está en estado P.

Answer (score 1):

Itera tus documentos y en el value del option guarda el estado.

```
// usando mysqli
while($documento -> $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    <option value="<?= $documento->estado; ?>" onChange="onDocSeleccionado(this)">
        <?= documento->nombre;?>
    </option>
<=php } ?>
```

Fíjate que le hemos asociado una función en cuanto se seleccione un ítem. En esa función se obtiene el valor seleccionado y se comprueba la condición. Si la cumple se activa el botón.

```
function onDocSeleccionado(e) {
  if(e.value === 'P') {
    document.getElementById('btn-ajustar').removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En las funciones `ejecutar` o donde pueda cambiar el estado se puede llamar a otra función `habilitarControles`

```
function habilitarControles(){
    document.getElementById("ajustar").disabled = estado!='P';
}
```

hay que ponerle el id a los botones (o cambiar `getElementById` por `getElementsByName` y buscar el primero)